# Disabling storing what you have entered before?

Tags: html

Im having a search field. Now when i search for names, it stores it.. Stores it you know so you can just press key down and enter then get the name you entered previously.. Im talking about the normal dropdown that comes when you have searched for some stuff in google example.. then you can key down and see everything you have searched before.

Is there any way to disable that to my search field? because i already have a ajax autosuggest function, and its not looking good when that comes..

Or any idea to bypass this/come around?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the `autocomplete` attribute on forms or input elements.

See:

- https://developer.mozilla.org/en/How_to_Turn_Off_Form_Autocompletion
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms533486%28VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can disable autocomplete. Keep in mind that autocomplete is a non-standard attribute, so it may not always work.

```
autocomplete="off"
```